# Combine results of two tables having different structure

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables:

**Event**

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `event` (
          `eventId` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
          `eventTime` bigint(20) NOT NULL COMMENT 'ex: 1431201865000 (epoch is milliseconds)',
          `sourceId` bigint(20) NOT NULL COMMENT 'ex: pole-code: 1 = JA005, patrolCarCode: 5000 = D4588',
          `plateNumber` varchar(40) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL COMMENT 'ex: 5849',
          `plateGps` varchar(40) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'ex: 0.000000 N  0.000000 E') 
    ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
```

**Source**

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `source` (
  `sourceId` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `sourceName` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL COMMENT 'ex: pole-code: JA005, patrolCarCode:D4588',
  `sourceSimIp` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'ex: 192.55.44.22',
  `sourceGps` varchar(40) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Only for Fixed source (Poles) ex: 25.110227 N  55.239798 E, 24.993183 N  55.250382 E, 0.000000 N  0.000000 E',
  PRIMARY KEY (`sourceId`),
  KEY `sourceName` (`sourceName`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
```

**Sample Data**

```
INSERT INTO `source` (`sourceId`, `sourceName`, `sourceSimIp`, `sourceGps`) VALUES
    (1, 'Pole 1', '74.200.230.71', '7.8731 N  80.7718 E'),
    (2, 'Car 1', '40.214.203.72', '')


INSERT INTO `event` (`eventId`, `eventTime`, `sourceId`, `plateNumber`, `plateGps`) 
VALUES
    (1, 1498806550534, 1, '1111', null),
    (2, 1498806550544, 2, '1111', '7.2936 N 80.6413 E'),
    (3, 1498806550554, 2, '1111', '7.9570 N 80.7601 E'),
    (4, 1498806550564, 2, '1112', '7.9580 N 80.7601 E'),
    (5, 1498806550584, 1, '1111', null),
    (6, 1498806550574, 1, '1111', '7.3010 N 80.3872 E')
```

**Question:**

There are two types of sources.
 1. Static Source (POLE CAMERA)
 2. Dynamic Source (MOVING CAR CAMERA)

In event table, If new entry is coming from static source, we already have GPS value for it saved in source table, so we save just source id and keep plateGPS field blank, but for Dynamic source we do not have GPS value in source table because source is dynamic and each event has different location which is saved in plateGps field of event table along with source Id pointing to source table(just for reference).

Now I need to construct a query where user will specify 'PlateNumber' and i need to check all its GPS occurrences in our system in order by eventTime.

One PlateNumber can be detected by static source and dynamic source so I am looking for dynamic way to get GPS occurrences from both of them.

I was able to create below query but it does not take care of **order by eventTime limitation.**

```
select source.sourceGps  as 'sourceGps' from source where source.sourceId in (select event.sourceId   from event  where eventTime >= 1488312001000 and eventTime <= 1513886399000 and event.plateNumber = '1111' and plateGps is null) 
 union all 
select plateGps as 'sourceGps'  from event  where eventTime >= 1488312001000 and eventTime <= 1513886399000  and event.plateNumber = '1111' and length(plateGps) > 0
```

**Can anyone help me with that?**

Comment: I think sample data and desired results would really help.

Comment: I have uploaded sample data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps you just need a `left join` with `order by`:

```
select coalesce(s.sourceGps, e.plateGps) as sourceGps, 
from event e left join
     source s
     on s.sourceId = e.sourceId  
where e.eventTime >= 1488312001000 and e.eventTime <= 1513886399000 and
      e.plateNumber = '5327'
order by e.eventTime;
```

Comment: Your query seems to have some typos, any how I will try and update you if it works for me. I have updated it to run with mysql.

select coalesce(s.sourceGps, e.plateGps) as sourceGps
from event e left join  source s
     on s.sourceId = e.sourceId  
where e.eventTime >= 1488312001000 and e.eventTime <= 1513886399000 and
      e.plateNumber = '5327'
order by e.eventTime;

Comment: Your query is returning empty string for plateGps column value where source is dynamic.